# Overriding the cell templates of a WPF GridViewRowPresenter

Tags: wpf, celltemplate

I'm producing a custom control that uses a [GridViewRowPresenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewrowpresenter.aspx) in a similar way to the way that the [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx) does - binding to the `Columns` collection of a `View` property on my control which is of type [ViewBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbase.aspx):

```
<GridViewRowPresenter Content="{Binding Content}" 
    Columns="{Binding Path=View.Columns, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MyControlType}}}" />
```

This means that users of the control are able to specify the columns using the familiar `GridView` style syntax, for example:

```
<MyControlType><MyControlType.View><GridView>
    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
    <GridViewColumn Header="Address" CellTemplate="{StaticResource MyCellTemplate}" />
</GridView></MyControlType.View></MyControlType>
```

This works fine, however my control (the `MyControlType`) need to be able to "override" the cell template for the columns in my grid so that they includes some additional content.

How can I do this with minimal change to the syntax users of the control need to write?